# Why am i getting two different urls for the same "story" in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently created a profile page for the users of the app am developing but along the way i noticed that the URL for the story originally is a little different from the same story on the users page. e.g normal url is "http://localhost:3000/genres/action/stories/37" while it is "http://localhost:3000/genres/absurdist/stories/37", meanwhile the story originally belongs to "action genre" and not "absurdist". Meanwhile, the two urls directs to the normal story page.

genre.rb

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stories, dependent: :destroy

  is_impressionable

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed?
  end
end
```

story.rb

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :genre
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy

  is_impressionable

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    title_changed?
  end

  has_attached_file :image, size: { less_than: 1.megabyte }, styles: { medium: "300x300#", wide: "200x400#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  scope :of_followed_users, -> (following_users) { where user_id: following_users }
end
```

profiles_controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user
  before_action :find_genre
  before_action :owned_profile, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @stories = User.find_by(user_name: params[:user_name]).stories.order('created_at DESC')
    impressionist(@user)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(profile_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Your profile has been updated.'
      redirect_to profile_path(@user.user_name)
    else
      @user.errors.full_messages
      flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :bio)
  end

  def find_user
    @user = User.find_by(user_name: params[:user_name])
  end

  def find_genre
    @genre = Genre.friendly.find_by(params[:slug])
  end

  def owned_profile
    @user = User.find_by(user_name: params[:user_name])
    unless current_user == @user
      flash[:alert] = "That profile does not belong to you"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

profiles show

```
<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="card-columns clearfix">
    <%= render @user.stories %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would say that you are needlessly nesting the URL. Since each story has a unique ID you should just have `/stories/:id` route to the show view. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Comment: sorry, i don't get you, can you explain more? I will read that.

Comment: Since each story has a unique id `/genres/action/stories/37` would actually point to the exact same resource as `/genres/absurdist/stories/37`. This means that the context `/genres/:genre_id` is not needed.

Comment: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Comment: Look at this: scope shallow_prefix: "sekret" do
   resources :genres do
     resources :stories, shallow: true
   end
   resources :stories do
     resources :episodes, shallow: true
   end
   resources :episodes do
     resources :comments, shallow: true
   end
 end

Comment: Be careful, routing is completely oblivious of your models parenthood. I was wondering the same thing as you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445720/do-i-need-my-routes-map-my-models-parenthood read Jamis buck also. Basically if there are ids that can be changed without causing an error it's because you are not using it, then you can make shorter routes

Comment: @max actually told me to read that of which i did but i was getting undefined method for "map". Did you later found a solution to it? Please share.